# Is there a way to "remesh" a mesh with even edge loops?

Tags: mesh, edit-mode

I made a mesh manually, but I want the mesh to be remeshed in such a way that the edge loops that comprise it are all as evenly spaced as possible, similar to what bevels do on their own along a single curve. Is there any addon for that?

Answer (score 3):

If you search for an addon called Loop Tools, they allow to space vertices or edges. Once you have enabled this addon, select all the vertices or edges you want to space, press W --> Loop Tools --> Space.

Comment: I don't understand what this tool is doing, it just terribly deforms the mesh in random ways.

Comment: Make sure you are selecting each edge loop individually and doing the above to each one separately and not all at once.